# How to store data in dataset without using Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to store data in the front end using data set without database? i have to store my data in c# without using the back end database.

Comment: Do you mean something like this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VmFdYWdSSU

Comment: You can store your data in various ways, they all have ups and downs. IsolatedStorage, Xml file, binary file, cloud, ...

Comment: i'am not sure , but i think that you want to use a cache in your client to store data ? could you specify which type of data do you want store ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use xml. For further information: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) & [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws09ehyc(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws09ehyc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is use this namespace

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
 using System.Reflection;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using static DataStoreServiceNameSpace.DataStoreServiceMain;
 namespace DataStoreService
{

public struct DataStore
{
    public string Name = "ERROR";
    public string filepath = "ERROR";
    public string path = "ERROR";

    public DataStore(string ACCESSCODE = "IMINTROUBLE")
    {
        if (ACCESSCODE == "CODE-PASS-ID:6t2uy3i2u3i2132131io31oi31u31ou3i1o3")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("DataStores Must Be Declared Using DataStoreService.GetDataStore");
        }
    }
    public string GetAsync(string key)
    {


        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
        string data = "";
        bool FoundData = false;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] split = line.Split('"');
            if (split == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Can not find key:" + key + ". Did you forget to use DataStore.SetAsync");
            }
            if (split[0] == key)
            {
                FoundData = true;
                data = split[1];
            }
        }
        if (FoundData == false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Can not find key:" + key + ". Did you forget to use DataStore.SetAsync");
        }
        return data;
    }
    public bool SetAysnc(string key, string data)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
        bool FoundData = false;
        int position = -1;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] split = line.Split('"');

            if (split[0] == key)
            {
                position = i;
                FoundData = true;
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if (FoundData)
        {
            lines[position] = key + '"' + data;
            File.WriteAllLines(filepath, lines);

        }
        else
        {
            string[] e = { key + '"' + data };
            File.AppendAllLines(filepath, e);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
public  class DataStoreServiceMain  
{
    

 
    

    public DataStoreServiceNameSpace.DataStore
        GetDataStore(string name)
    {
        DataStoreServiceNameSpace.DataStore d = new DataStoreServiceNameSpace.DataStore("CODE-PASS-ID:6t2uy3i2u3i2132131io31oi31u31ou3i1o3");
        d.path = GetType().Assembly.Location;
        d.filepath = Directory.GetParent(d.path).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName + "/DataStores/" + name + ".bendata";
        d.Name = name;
        if (File.Exists(d.filepath))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            FileStream file = File.Create(d.filepath);
            file.Close();
        }
        return d;
    }
}
}
```

set up a folder in the directory of the file and call it (DataStores)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).